# Failing to install (compile) minpack.lm on Mac M1

Tags: r, package

I am attempting to install the package `minpack.lm` on R 4.2.2, running on macOS Ventura with an M1 Pro chip. I attempted installing from source, but get the following errors during install:
[image]

I inspected my directory and the folder `/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch-64-apple-darwin21/12` does exist.

Question: How can I fix this problem and install minpack.lm?

Thanks for helping!

Edit 1: Installing from binary does not seem possible.
[image]

Edit 2: Installing with `type = "mac.binary"` succeeds, but then leads to an error when loading the package:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution was to reinstall R using:

```
brew install --cask r
brew install --cask xquartz
```

Then, installing `minpack.lm` via its binaries worked fine:

```
> install.packages("minpack.lm") # works!
```

However, installing from source would still lead to an error about gfortran missing: `/opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran: No such file or directory`.
The issue is related to changes to homebrew, where the gfortran recipe was integrated into gcc, causing a compilation error in new systems (since cannot find gfortran where expected). See this [blog post](https://cynkra.com/blog/2021-03-16-gfortran-macos/) and this [other blog post](https://pat-s.me/transitioning-from-x86-to-arm64-on-macos-experiences-of-an-r-user/) for more detailed explanations.

In order to be able to also install the package from source, an explicit installation of gfortran is necessary. For that, please refer to the instructions under "GNU Fortran compiler" in the [mac.r-project.org](https://mac.r-project.org/tools/) website.

I appreciate the help of the minpack.lm package author in finding this solution.